# How do I get the dimensions of an A4 page without querying a printer?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I know I can connect to a printer and call GetPrinterCapabilities, which will return a list of the pages that the printer is capable of printing too, along with their actual sizes.

But, is there a way to get a PageMediaSize for a given PageMediaSizeName without querying a PrintQueue?

Comment: what is the problem with using GetPrinterCapabilities?

Comment: A4 has a fixed size, so you could hardcode it, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a guarenteed known printer that contains A4 in its list of supported paper sizes?

And yes, if I can't query something in .net for the size I will hardcode the dimesions.